# How to allow infinite integer values in a spinner?

Tags: python, kivy

I need a [`Spinner`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinner_%28computing%29) widget in which the user can select **integer** values with a certain step and without lower or upper limits
(I mean, they should be at least in the billion range, so no chance of memorizing the whole sequence).

I saw kivy's [`Spinner`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.spinner.html) widget but I don't think doing something like `Spinner(values=itertool.count())` would work.
Also it is limited to string values.

Is there any simple way of obtaining something similar to [`QSpinBox`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qspinbox.html) of the `Qt`?

Comment: I've never used it, but this Kivy widget appears to be misnamed (it looks awfully like a drop down list).

Comment: @delnan Yes, I thought that too. Resembles so much a `QComboBox`. I just realized that the [`Slider`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.slider.html) class seems to provide some way to get numbers from the user but I don't like much the look and, since the range can be really big, the users wont have enough control on the step. Well, I'll try to implement one by hand in the meanwhile.

Comment: If you look at the android [spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) it's pretty similar to what the Kivy Spinner is like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like kivy at the moment does not provide anything similar to a `Spinner` or `SpinBox` or however you want to call it. A widget that might be used instead is the [`Slider`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.slider.html) but it looks awful and it's not so useful if you want to allow a very big range but with a small step.

Therefore I wrote my own implementation of a `SpinBox`:

```
class SpinBox(BoxLayout):
    """A widget to show and take numeric inputs from the user.

    :param min_value: Minimum of the range of values.
    :type min_value: int, float
    :param max_value: Maximum of the range of values.
    :type max_value: int, float
    :param step: Step of the selection
    :type step: int, float
    :param value: Initial value selected
    :type value: int, float
    :param editable: Determine if the SpinBox is editable or not
    :type editable: bool
    """

    min_value = NumericProperty(float('-inf'))
    max_value = NumericProperty(float('+inf'))
    step = NumericProperty(1)
    value = NumericProperty(0)
    range = ReferenceListProperty(min_value, max_value, step)

    def __init__(self, btn_size_hint_x=0.2, **kwargs):
        super(SpinBox, self).__init__(orientation='horizontal', **kwargs)

        self.value_label = Label(text=str(self.value))
        self.inc_button = TimedButton(text='+')
        self.dec_button = TimedButton(text='-')

        self.inc_button.bind(on_press=self.on_increment_value)
        self.inc_button.bind(on_time_slice=self.on_increment_value)
        self.dec_button.bind(on_press=self.on_decrement_value)
        self.dec_button.bind(on_time_slice=self.on_decrement_value)

        self.buttons_vbox = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical',
                                      size_hint_x=btn_size_hint_x)
        self.buttons_vbox.add_widget(self.inc_button)
        self.buttons_vbox.add_widget(self.dec_button)

        self.add_widget(self.value_label)
        self.add_widget(self.buttons_vbox)

    def on_increment_value(self, btn_instance):
        if float(self.value) + float(self.step) <= self.max_value:
            self.value += self.step

    def on_decrement_value(self, btn_instance):
        if float(self.value) - float(self.step) >= self.min_value:
            self.value -= self.step

    def on_value(self, instance, value):
        instance.value_label.text = str(value)
```

Actually the code I use is slightly different because I think it is ugly to subclass a layout to implement a widget and thus I subclassed `Widget` and added a horizontal `BoxLayout` as only children of the `Widget`, then I `bind`ed every size and position change to update the size and position of this child(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029010/why-does-the-root-widget-not-have-the-same-size-of-the-window) question for why I had to do that).

The `TimedButton` is a subclass of `Button` that allows long-presses and, when long-pressed, emits a `on_time_slice` event every a certain amount of millisecond(thus the user will be able to hold the button to do a continuous increment). You can simply use a normal `Button` if you want, removing the `bind`s to `on_time_slice` event.

The `TimedButton` source code is this:

```
class TimedButton(Button):
    """A simple ``Button`` subclass that produces an event at regular intervals
    when pressed.

    This class, when long-pressed, emits an ``on_time_slice`` event every
    ``time_slice`` milliseconds.

    :param long_press_interval: Defines the minimum time required to consider
                                the press a long-press.
    :type long_press_interval: int
    :param time_slice: The number of milliseconds of each slice.
    :type time_slice: int
    """

    def __init__(self, long_press_interval=550, time_slice=225, **kwargs):
        super(TimedButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.long_press_interval = long_press_interval
        self.time_slice = time_slice

        self._touch_start = None
        self._long_press_callback = None
        self._slice_callback = None

        self.register_event_type('on_time_slice')
        self.register_event_type('on_long_press')


    def on_state(self, instance, value):
        if value == 'down':
            start_time = time.time()
            self._touch_start = start_time

            def callback(dt):
                self._check_long_press(dt)

            Clock.schedule_once(callback, self.long_press_interval / 1000.0)
            self._long_press_callback = callback
        else:
            end_time = time.time()
            delta = (end_time - (self._touch_start or 0)) * 1000
            Clock.unschedule(self._slice_callback)
            # Fixes the bug of multiple presses causing fast increase
            Clock.unschedule(self._long_press_callback)
            if (self._long_press_callback is not None and
                delta > self.long_press_interval):
                self.dispatch('on_long_press')
            self._touch_start = None
            self._long_press_callback = self._slice_callback = None

    def _check_long_press(self, dt):
        delta = dt * 1000
        if delta > self.long_press_interval and self.state == 'down':
            self.dispatch('on_long_press')
            self._long_press_callback = None

            def slice_callback(dt):
                self.dispatch('on_time_slice')
                return self.state == 'down'

            Clock.schedule_interval(slice_callback, self.time_slice / 1000.0)

            self._slice_callback = slice_callback


    def on_long_press(self):
        pass

    def on_time_slice(self):
        pass
```

Note that I had to bind the `state` property instead of using `on_touch_down` and `on_touch_up` because they give some [strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074979/bind-working-at-random-times), and even when "working" there were some strange things happening by no reason(e.g. clicking the decrement button caused `on_increment` to be called even though the `bind`ings where correct).

---

**Edit:** Updated the `TimedButton` class fixing a little bug(the previous implementation when clicked rapidly multiple times and then holding down the button would yield too many `on_time_slice` events: I'd forgot to "unschedule" the `_long_press_callback` when the state goes `'normal'`

Comment: By default the on_touch_* events in kivy don't [check for collision](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/inputs.html#touch-events) to the widget, you have to do that manually by calling [collide_point](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=collide_point#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.collide_point) which could account for the issues faced by you. [Button](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html) provides `on_press` and `on_release` events which can be used directly without having to worry about that. In your case using `state` property makes much more sense.