# Bind working at random times

Tags: python, kivy

I'm writing a custom widget for kivy(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073807/how-to-allow-infinite-integer-values-in-a-spinner) question), but I just found out that, for some unknown reason, sometimes the `bind` method does not actually bind the callbacks.

In my class I have this code:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(SpinBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    self._value_label = Label(text=str(self.value))
    self.inc_button = TimedButton(text='+')
    self.dec_button = TimedButton(text='-')


    def inc(inst):
        if float(self.value) + float(self.step) <= self.max_value:
            self.value += self.step

    def dec(inst):
        if float(self.value) - float(self.step) >= self.min_value:
            self.value -= self.step

    self.inc_button.bind(on_press=inc)
    self.inc_button.bind(on_time_slice=inc)
    self.dec_button.bind(on_press=dec)
    self.dec_button.bind(on_time_slice=dec)
    # ...
```

Where `TimedButton` is an other custom class. It is a `Button` subclass that on `on_touch_down` starts a timer, if after a certain amount of time it didn't receive a `on_touch_up` it consider the press a long-press and starts to dispatch the `on_time_slice` event using `Clock.schedule_interval` every some milliseconds.

So, trying to use my custom class like this:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SpinBox()

MyApp().run()
```

The `value` is not incremented at all.

If I do:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        s = SpinBox()
        def inc(inst):
            s.value += 1
        s.inc_button.bind(on_time_slice=inc)
        return s
MyApp().run()
```

The value *is* incremented at every `on_time_slice` event. I don't understand why the bind inside the `MyApp` class works, while binding in the `SpinBox.__init__` method does not.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work around. Instead of binding the `on_touch_down` and `on_touch_up` I tried to bind the `state` property implementing an `on_state` method in the `TimedButton` and it works. I still don't understand why the previous implementation worked when used alone but not in the `SpinBox`, except when binding a function inside the `App` class directly.

Anyway, since it looks like the `TimedButton` class has something to do with it, here's the code of the old implementation:

```
class TimedButton(Button):
    """A simple ``Button`` subclass that produces an event at regular intervals
    when pressed.

    This class, when long-pressed, emits an ``on_time_slice`` event every
    ``time_slice`` milliseconds.

    :param long_press_interval: Defines the minimum time required to consider
                                the press a long-press.
    :type long_press_interval: int
    :param time_slice: The number of milliseconds of each slice.
    :type time_slice: int
    """

    def __init__(self, long_press_interval=550, time_slice=225, **kwargs):
        super(TimedButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.long_press_interval = long_press_interval
        self.time_slice = time_slice

        self._touch_start = None
        self._touch_uid = None
        self._long_press_callback = None
        self._slice_callback = None

        self.register_event_type('on_time_slice')
        self.register_event_type('on_long_press')


    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        start_time = time.time()
        self._touch_start = start_time
        self._touch_uid = touch.uid

        def callback(dt):
            self._check_long_press(dt)

        Clock.schedule_once(callback, self.long_press_interval / 1000.0)
        self._long_press_callback = callback
        super(TimedButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def _check_long_press(self, dt):
        delta = dt * 1000
        if delta > self.long_press_interval and self._touch_uid is not None:
            self.dispatch('on_long_press')
            self._long_press_callback = None
            def slice_callback(dt):
                self.dispatch('on_time_slice')

            Clock.schedule_interval(slice_callback, self.time_slice / 1000.0)

            self._slice_callback = slice_callback

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        end_time = time.time()
        delta = (end_time - (self._touch_start or 0)) * 1000
        Clock.unschedule(self._slice_callback)
        if (self._long_press_callback is not None and
                delta > self.long_press_interval):
            self.dispatch('on_long_press')
        self._touch_start = self._touch_uid = None
        self._long_press_callback = self._slice_callback = None
        super(TimedButton, self).on_touch_up(touch)


    def on_long_press(self):
        pass

    def on_time_slice(self):
        pass
```

And here's the new code using `state` which works perfectly well:

```
class TimedButton(Button):
    """A simple ``Button`` subclass that produces an event at regular intervals
    when pressed.

    This class, when long-pressed, emits an ``on_time_slice`` event every
    ``time_slice`` milliseconds.

    :param long_press_interval: Defines the minimum time required to consider
                                the press a long-press.
    :type long_press_interval: int
    :param time_slice: The number of milliseconds of each slice.
    :type time_slice: int
    """

    def __init__(self, long_press_interval=550, time_slice=225, **kwargs):
        super(TimedButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.long_press_interval = long_press_interval
        self.time_slice = time_slice

        self._touch_start = None
        self._long_press_callback = None
        self._slice_callback = None

        self.register_event_type('on_time_slice')
        self.register_event_type('on_long_press')


    def on_state(self, instance, value):
        if value == 'down':
            start_time = time.time()
            self._touch_start = start_time

            def callback(dt):
                self._check_long_press(dt)

            Clock.schedule_once(callback, self.long_press_interval / 1000.0)
            self._long_press_callback = callback
        else:
            end_time = time.time()
            delta = (end_time - (self._touch_start or 0)) * 1000
            Clock.unschedule(self._slice_callback)
            if (self._long_press_callback is not None and
                delta > self.long_press_interval):
                self.dispatch('on_long_press')
            self._touch_start = None
            self._long_press_callback = self._slice_callback = None

    def _check_long_press(self, dt):
        delta = dt * 1000
        if delta > self.long_press_interval and self.state == 'down':
            self.dispatch('on_long_press')
            self._long_press_callback = None

            def slice_callback(dt):
                self.dispatch('on_time_slice')
                return self.state == 'down'

            Clock.schedule_interval(slice_callback, self.time_slice / 1000.0)

            self._slice_callback = slice_callback


    def on_long_press(self):
        pass

    def on_time_slice(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Your TimedButton is exactly what I'm looking for. Did you ever try to make a function to speed things up after a certain point? For example, once ``on_long_press`` has been called 20 times, the times get faster.